# cloudera installation process and clustering in local network

Tags: cloudera, cdap

How to install cloudera in local system .I'm using centos 6.5.And also I want to do clustering in cloudera .Any one suggest me some documentation to this process properly

Answer (score 0):

You can either use VM or Docker. Please follow the instructions [here](https://www.cloudera.com/downloads/quickstart_vms/5-13.html) to get it installed locally.